# htaccess rewrite urls beginning with same words and ending with different numbers

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I searched the web an could not find an answer for this htaccess issue.

I have a broken site with many product URLs like:

de/biegsames-uhrenmannchen-flexi-4102193
de/biegsames-uhrenmannchen-flexi-4102200
 
de/biegsames-uhrenmannchen-flexi-4102200 
de/biegsames-uhrenmannchen-flexi-4102207

I'd like to redirect all URLs to

de/biegsames-uhrenmannchen-flexi

I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^de/biegsames-uhrenmannchen-flexi* /de/biegsames-uhrenmannchen-flexi
```

but with no change. How can I redirect multiple URLs regarding just the first words and ignore everything behind the *?

like: url-bla-bla-bla* --> goes to url-bla-bla

So

url-bla-bla-bla-ui-ui-ui 
url-bla-bla-bla-oh-oh

--> would be redirected to url-bla-bla.

Every help is appreciated and I am so thankful, since I have to fix thousands of broken URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U could try:

```
RewriteRule ^de/biegsames-uhrenmannchen-flexi(.*)$ /de/biegsames-uhrenmannchen-flexi [R=301,L]
```

**(.*)$** = everything that comes after de/biegsames-uhrenmannchen-flexi.

**[R=301,L]** = permanent redirect and the L means to stop applying any rules that follow.

Comment: Thanks, this will help me speed up my image serving by redirecting not found image files to new url to create the file and serve it.